# Android Amazon S3 file upload not working

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a file on the sd card to my amazon s3 bucket. Here is the class:

```
public class FileUploadDownload
{
    Context context;
    boolean transferComplete = false;
    float transferPercentage = 0;
    public FileUploadDownload(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void uploadFile(File file , String nameOfFile)
    {
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                "cognito_identity_pool_id", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
        );
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                "s3_bucket",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                nameOfFile,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                file        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"State changed to : "+state.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

              //  transferPercentage = (float)bytesCurrent/(float)bytesTotal;
                if(bytesCurrent == bytesTotal)
                {
                //    transferComplete = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Upload completed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Upload Unsuccessful due to `"+ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet which I am implementing in the OnCreate() method of the Activity:

```
 File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/EpisodeRecorder/User1/Episode1/User1e1p1.jpg");
    FileUploadDownload fud = new FileUploadDownload(this);
    fud.uploadFile(dir,"trialFileUpload.jpg");
```

Here is the top part of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />
.....
```

I am showing all the debug messages through toasts. Initially it shows "IN PROGRESS" and after a bit, it says "FAILED" 
the error message says "java.lang.IllegalStateException"
In the DEBUG LOG it says:

```
10-12 21:01:01.138   1252-14041/? E/CloudSettingsConnection﹕ Connection failed : SERVER_ERROR
```

I am not able to figure out what's happening. It would be great if you could point out the error. Or I'd be glad if you can figure out whether the error is in the Amazon s3 / cognito / IAM setup or the code. Thanks!

Here is the entire stack trace as asked:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x60970398: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:731)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:131)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$FixedLengthOutputStream.write(HttpTransport.java:236)
            at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.write(UrlHttpClient.java:172)
            at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:129)
            at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:353)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4204)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1618)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:174)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:74)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:40)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-13 00:37:56.427  14450-14483/? E/UploadTask﹕ Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x60970398: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-13 00:37:56.497  14450-14450/? D/UPLOAD FAIL﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transfer failed.
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? (Latest is 2.2.7)
Can you please post a full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I added these in the gradle build file under dependencies. So I assume that's the latest version of the sdk...
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'

Comment: Hmm I don't see anything wrong, and I just wrote a sample and it seemed to work fine.

Are you on wi-fi?
What is the strength of your connection?
Are you behind some kind of weird network barrier (proxy, firewall?)
Is this consistent or intermittent?

Comment: So there possiblycould be something wrong with the Cognito/IAM setup?

Comment: I am using my university Wifi... it's quite fast.

Comment: I used a vpn to connect now. Still gives the same error message

Comment: Could this be because I have not provided a valid payment method in the Amazon Web Services website?

Comment: With this error, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Can you follow https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3OR1UXXKSVGM3/Logging-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android and enable low level logging to see if we can get more information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will work for you, but I was experiencing the same problem and I figured out that the name of the file was having ".png" at the end, so I removed it and it worked, before removing it I checked the currentBytes, before it gives me FAILED state, the number of currentBytes was equal to totalBytes but I got state FAILED anyway, so

> try to remove any extension in the fileName

I hope this helps